# Perplexities about Bayesian inference and model averaging (BMA)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, bayesian

reading about Bayesian approach on model selection, I was just wondering about the more mathematical meaning of *Bayesian model averaging*.
Say for example that we are given a dataset $\mathcal{D} = \{\textbf{x}_i, y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ where $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^D$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and we ant to perform a regression task. With a Bayesian approach, after putting a **prior** on $\theta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, v^2I)$ we want to estimate the **posterior** distribution:

$$p(\theta|\mathcal{D}) = \frac{p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)p(\theta)}{p(\mathcal{D})}$$

and finally the **predictive posterior**:

$$p(y|x,\mathcal{D}) = \int_{\theta \in \Theta}p(y|x, \mathcal{D},\theta)p(\theta|\mathcal{D})d\theta$$.

In particular the above quantity can also be considered as $\mathbb{E_{p(\theta|\mathcal{D})}[p(y|x,\mathcal{D},\theta)]}$.

So we're basically computing the expected value of the distribution $p(y|x,\mathcal{D},\theta)$ weighted by the posterior distribution (What does this mean, in **practice**?).

My issue is that I can't manage to actually visualize what is happening here.

Also, how can we get to the expression for the predictive distribution in a *rigorous mathematical manner*?

Another issue that I have is, say that we are not in the trivial case where both $p(\theta)\, , \, p(y|x,\mathcal{D}, \theta)$ are gaussians, so that the posterior doesn't have a closed form, but we can only approximate it (using for example *Gibbs Sampling*).

How does the above expression translates in this case?

I guess that in this case we only have access to, say $m$ samples from the posterior, so that

$$\mathbb{E}_{p(\theta|\mathcal{D})}[p(y|x,\mathcal{D},\theta)] \approx \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m p(y|x, \mathcal{D},\theta^{(i)})p(\theta^{(i)}|\mathcal{D})$$.

Is this writing correct?

Many thanks,

James

Comment: You might want to add that $p(\mathcal{D}) = \int\limits_{\theta \in \Theta} p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)p(\theta)\, d\theta$.  Your integrations may be easy (e.g. with a conjugate prior) or difficult (in which case you may want to use numerical or Monte Carlo methods), but the intuitive idea is that you update the prior with the likelihood of the observations to get the posterior distribution for the parameters, and then combine the posterior distribution with the likelihood to get the predictive distribution for new observations.